# Network Balancer for LAN?

Tags: networking, local-area-network

Can it be possible to give a higher priority to certain PC's internet speed? Curiosity ran into my mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[QoS.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service)

Comment: At which section of that page should I be reading.

Comment: Start at the beginning, and when you get to the end, stop.

Comment: Trollolol.....,

Comment: Note that QoS on your local router generally won't help when it's download speed you care about. Your local router doesn't get to choose which packets your ISP puts on the wire to you, only which packets it puts on the wire to your ISP.

Comment: @JackSpairow So let me revisit this. The reason for a terse response is that ServerFault is designed to target IT professionals and their questions, but only questions that have shown a due diligence of research. The question appears to be an off-the-cuff muse that does not have professional intent. A quick search of the internet could have satisfied your curiosity. Certainly I don't want to discourage questions or satisfying curiosity, however ServerFault isn't the best place for this kind of conversation. Perhaps another forum like DaniWeb? Keep being curious.